# setting custom time in flipclock plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, flipclock

I am struggling with Flipclock http://flipclockjs.com/ . I browsed their website but i can't find a hint on how to change the time.

What i want to do is set the time i want to display. The problem is the browser on some smart TV's have a problem at changing the timezone so i wanted to get the time from the server with php but i can't set the time. This is my code. I only found some examples with countdown but that is not helpfull at all. It just uses the local time and it doesnt change at all. Thank you all in advance.

```
// Here i get the unix time from the server in a hidden field
ServerTime = $('#my_time').val();

// FlipClock initialization
clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
    autoStart: false,
    clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock'
});
var time = clock.getTime();
console.log(time);
clock.setTime(time + 3600);
clock.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

As i found out that FlipClock plugin somehow doesn't work with `setTime()` so i changed the code somewhere else. This is my initialization code for generating the FlipClockJS plugin.

```
 var clock;
 var index = '';
 $(document).ready(function() {
     clock = $('.clock').FlipClock({
         clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock'
     });
 });
```

The changes i did was in the file Flipclock.js . It's around the 1325 line. Search for `getMilitaryTime`

Original:

```
getMilitaryTime: function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var obj  = this.digitize([
        date.getHours(),
        date.getMinutes(),
        date.getSeconds()
    ]);

return obj;
},
```

Edited:

```
getMilitaryTime: function() {
    var date = new Date();

    /* The folowing code looks at my server time and if it's higher or smaller it adds so many hours it is missing */
    var ServerTime = $('#my_time').val();
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getHours();
    var diff = ServerTime - n;
    /*****************************************************************/

    var obj  = this.digitize([
        date.getHours()+(diff),
        date.getMinutes(),
        date.getSeconds()
    ]);

return obj;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// FlipClock initialization  
var ServerTime = $('#my_time').val();
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
var diff = ServerTime - n;
clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff,{  
    clockFace: 'TwentyFourHourClock'  
});
```

This should allow you to display your time without modifications to the source code.

Answer (score 1):

use this 100% work

```
<script>        
    var date = new Date('2016-11-07 07:00:0 am');
    clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(date, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true,
    showSeconds: false
    });
</script>
```

you can change the clockFace value as per your requirement.